# GnuPG 2.1.20 ssh agent forwarding with yubikey on OSX fails

Tags: ssh, gpg, gpg-agent, gnupg, yubikey

Tried out ProxyJump as suggested by @JensErat.

I configured it like this in ssh config:
Host jump-to-server
HostName server.hostname
ProxyJump ubuntu@jump.hostname
User ubuntu

But it does not work, it just hangs during connection.
Do I need gnupg installed on the jump server also?

I have 2 computers running OSX. home and laptop. I also have a number of servers that I need to access, let's refer to them all as server.

On home and laptop I have installed gnupg 2.1.20 and I have a yubikey that works on them both. I can connect to a server using the yubikey over ssh.

Servers only have regular ssh, no gnupg.

This works great using gnupg and yubikey:

```
home > server
laptop > server
laptop > home
```

I have added the following in .bash_profile on home and laptop to make this work:

```
if [ -f "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info" ]; then
  . "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info"
  export GPG_AGENT_INFO
  export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
fi
```

I would also like to do this

```
laptop > home > server
```

To do this I have read that I read I need to open an extra socket so this is .gnupg/gpg-agent.conf on laptop:

```
pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac
extra-socket /Users/deadlock/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
enable-ssh-support
write-env-file
use-standard-socket
default-cache-ttl 600
max-cache-ttl 7200
allow-preset-passphrase
```

This is the same on home:

```
pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac
enable-ssh-support
write-env-file
use-standard-socket
default-cache-ttl 600
max-cache-ttl 7200
```

gpg-agent is running on both laptop and home; I have made sure ssh-agent is NOT running.

I have configured home like this in ~/.ssh/config

```
Host home
HostName 12.34.45.67
Port 22
User jens
ForwardAgent no
RemoteForward /Users/jens/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent /Users/jens/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
```

This does not work. On laptop, `ssh-add -l` lists my keys, but after I try to ssh home. I cannot ssh further to server. It just hangs or fails with that it could not authenticate.

If possible I would also be able to do this

```
laptop > server > server
```

but since server is not running gnupg at all I don't know if it is possible?

Comment: This is not an immediate solution to the problem you want to solve (getting agent forwarding running), but did you consider using the new jumphost feature of OpenSSH? Using "home" as a jump host, you should be able to connect through home while both connections (laptop to home, laptop to server through home) are initiated on the laptop.

Comment: Interesting @JensErat can you send a link on how to set it up?

Comment: [Wikibooks has some information](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Passing_Through_One_or_More_Gateways_Using_ProxyJump), there are also plenty of other resources. Works very well with the combination of GnuPG and a Yubikey, by the way -- I'm using such a setup since OpenSSH 7.3 was released.

Comment: I tried it out, please see my edited question @JensErat

Comment: Ah it hanged because a misspelling in the hostname :) Works now, this solutions is perfect! Thanks @JensErat